# Checkbox as image - Background Color

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have followed this link for image Checkboxes

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/xP2Ns/.  THe scripts and css worked perfectly.

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/raz13m.jpg");
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
 }
```

My issue is am trying to set `background-color` if the user clicks the Checkbox:

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
 }
```

And the background-color is not looking like i expected and am looking for same as fiddle o/p.

[image: Attached my o/p]

how can i fix this or do i miss something ?

In my HTML  i give

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="styled green" />(green)
<p>
```

but still it is applying to entire SPAN. Am not sure what am doing wrong !

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xP2Ns/1241/ (works only on green for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to know the background color (eg green), in the `DoCheck` function you can check the class and add a new class containing the background (eg greenchecked).

You can use the same approach for other colors.

Example:

```
.greencheck {
    background-color: green;
}

function doCheck() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        if($(this).hasClass('green')){
            $(this).removeClass('greencheck');
        }
        $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        if($(this).hasClass('green')){
            $(this).addClass('greencheck');
        }
        $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
    }
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xP2Ns/1241/

Comment: Updated my question.the Basic HTML background is not coming properly fr me.Any idea wat causing it ?

Comment: Works fine for me, can you provide a jsfiddle with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `background-color` for the `span`, not `checkbox`.

For example, you can do like this ( for `.purple` ) :

**JQuery**

```
if($(this).hasClass("purple")){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xP2Ns/1240/)